# Is it possible to nest all 4 of these nested For loops into one For loop with an extra level?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I'm learning Python from a textbook and one of the exercises (there is no answer key available!) wants you to create 4 patterns of asterisks.  This code creates the correct output.

As you can see it is 4 separate code blocks each with nested For Loops. My question is to whether it is possible to put it all into 1 For loop that is nested one level deeper (e.g. For group in range(4) > For row in range(10) > For asterisk in range(etc.)?  Or since the output of each code block is different, is this most granular I could go?

Any insight is much appreciated!

```py
for row in range(10):
    for asterisk in range(row + 1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()

print()
for row in range(10):
    for asterisk in range(10 - row):
        print('*', end='')
    print()

print()
for row in range(10):
    print(' ' * row, end='')
    for asterisk in range(10 - row):
        print('*', end='')
    print()

print()
for row in range(10):
    print(' ' * (9 - row), end='')
    for asterisk in range(row + 1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think it will make the code any clearer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, it is possible. I'm sure this is not your actual question. I assume you want some guidance as to how to do it; but "some guidance" [isn't a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) and simply showing the resulting code [isn't very helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822). *What exactly do you find difficult* about the task? When you wrote the existing code for the existing `for` loops, how did you know what to write? What, in your mind, is preventing you from applying the same techniques again?

Comment: (Hint: **what changes** between each block of code? **What stays the same**? Can you think of a way to *use data* to represent the differences?)

Comment: (As an aside: try doing `'*' * 5`. What is the result? Do you see how you can use this fact to simplify the program logic?)

Comment: Not only you can multiply strings (as you did in the last two loops), but you can also add (`+`) them. This is going to be handy for the last two patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Before trying to push the code into another level of `for` loops, let's try to make a *function* that represents the needed logic for each part.

Start with one version of the code, and stub out the parts that change. Add a function header, and stub out the parameters for now.

```
def triangle(...):
    for row in range(10):
        ...
        for asterisk in range(...):
            print('*', end='')
        print()
```

Notice that I did not include the `print` in between the triangles. That has separate logic (we want to do it every time except the first; not because of what kind of triangle we're drawing)

Before we try to figure out how to fill in the blanks, let's try to simplify the code by using what we already know. The existing code uses `print(' ' * row, end='')` or `print(' ' * (9 - row), end='')` to print a specific number of spaces (determined by `row`). The `for` loop is used to print a specific number of asterisks. Clearly, we can use the `*` technique instead. So:

```
def triangle(...):
    for row in range(10):
        ...
        print('*' * ..., end='')
        print()
```

And having done that, we see that we have a `print` that deliberately suppresses the newline at the end, immediately followed by an empty `print` used only to display a newline. That doesn't make a lot of sense. We could just:

```
def triangle(...):
    for row in range(10):
        ...
        print('*' * ...)
```

Much better.

Next: is our logic actually conditional? In the original versions of the code, we sometimes had a `print` for some spaces, and other times not. But we can unify that: "not printing spaces" is the same thing as "printing zero spaces"; so really all we need is a *rule that tells us how many* spaces to print, and then we can use the same structure every time:

```
def triangle(...):
    for row in range(10):
        print(' ' * ..., end='')
        print('*' * ...)
```

In fact, we can combine these `print`s. We want to print two things one right after the other (i.e. with an empty `sep` in between), and we want the default newline to be printed after that. So:

```
def triangle(...):
    for row in range(10):
        print(' ' * ..., '*' * ..., sep='')
```

Much better. On to the part where we actually fill in the blanks.

First off, what information do we have to pass in? We need to know two things: whether to right-align the triangle, and whether to print it upside-down or not. So those are our parameters:

```
def triangle(upside_down, right):
    for row in range(10):
        print(' ' * ..., '*' * ..., sep='')
```

What is the rule that tells us how many stars to print?

If the triangle is right-side-up, then we print `row + 1` stars. Otherwise we need `10 - row` stars. That matches the values that were passed to `range` in the original code.

```
def triangle(upside_down, right):
    for row in range(10):
        stars = 10 - row if upside_down else row + 1
        print(' ' * ..., '*' * stars, sep='')
```

What is the rule that tells us how many spaces to print?

If the triangle is right-aligned, then we should print some spaces. How many? Well, for an upside-down triangle we used the `row` number directly. For a right-side-up triangle we need `9 - row` stars. But we can simplify this, by thinking in terms of the *remaining* space after we account for the stars. We want a total of 10 stars plus spaces, so we can simply subtract `10 - stars` to get the space count.

If the triangle is left-aligned, of course, then we print zero spaces.

```
def triangle(upside_down, right):
    for row in range(10):
        stars = 10 - row if upside_down else row + 1
        spaces = 10 - stars if right else 0
        print(' ' * spaces, '*' * stars, sep='')
```

Simple. Let's use it:

```
triangle(False, False)
print()
triangle(True, False)
print()
triangle(True, True)
print()
triangle(False, True)
```

By *extracting* the code first, it becomes much clearer how to *iterate* that code: we just need to change the arguments for the `triangle` calls, and take care of the intermediate `print`s. We have a clearly defined function that does one thing and has a reasonable name - in accordance with all the principles that a good programming book tries to teach you.

How do we repeatedly call a function with differing, constant (i.e. pre-calculated) arguments? Simple: we put those arguments in some data structure, and iterate over that. To `print` after each `triangle` except the last, our trick is to instead `print` *before* each `triangle` except the *first*, using some simple flag logic (a variable that tells us what to display - either a newline, or nothing - which changes unconditionally *after* displaying it).

So, for example:

```
# This tells us which values we will use to call `triangle` each time.
configurations = ((False, False), (True, False), (True, True), (False, True))
# This tells us what we will display before each `triangle`.
before_triangle = ''
for upside_down, right in configurations:
    print(before_triangle, end='')
    before_triangle = '\n'
    triangle(upside_down, right)
```

Comment: One important thing about this answer (and the more simple but less programmatic solution with four loops that the textbook was surely expecting) is that it can be read aloud as "print this many asterisks and this many spaces". That makes the code easy to debug and reuse. All the other solutions using arbitrary patterns and many nested loops would be read as _Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn_, which is not very helpful.

Comment: I don't think the difference is quite that stark, but I did have that issue in mind.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly That sentence "print this many asterisks and this many spaces" is easy enough, but the configuration/logic of controlling that sentence isn't quite as trivial. I find my solution far simpler. (Plus it's more reusable, as I've shown with my bonus patterns.)

Comment: I agree. IMHO the textbook solution is easy to write/understand/debug, but it does nothing else (which is maybe enough). [Karl Knetchtel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72933100/15032126) is more difficult to write, but gives you a simple function that solves a particular problem, and you can reuse without knowing _how_ it does it. [Kelly Bundy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932936/15032126) is a lot more flexible, can be adapted to complex patterns, but how to get those patterns it's not trivial at all and, for simple ones it can be easier to use the textbook's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Going over the n×n grid and letting a pattern expression decide whether to print an `*`:

```
n = 10

h = n / 2
patterns = [
    lambda: i >= j,
    lambda: i+j < n,
    lambda: j >= i,
    lambda: i+j >= n-1,
]

for p in patterns:
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(' *'[p()], end='')
        print()
    print()
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BDoIwEETv/Yq5GFqpQfFijPgjhEMJKG1kbQoHTfx3bFUOVfeys29ms1l7H7srbXfWTROhwGbNWOc7IUPOrBrH1tHgQcng66L6ulF7aBwLGBmz1OAAiqEJQf0b9JRWm5j36sa1NCKYXWypeuB61Yk0COOFv/QV4TrLcjxgfBNYIJesYux0dbDQhPmV/WspYB2wU3RuOYk3ni3z3wplnaaRJ1gmpeWikmipKZJEsDjwnj96mp4)):

```
*         
**        
***       
****      
*****     
******    
*******   
********  
********* 
**********

**********
********* 
********  
*******   
******    
*****     
****      
***       
**        
*         

**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *

         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

Bonus patterns:

```
    lambda: max(i,j) >= h,
    lambda: abs(i-h)+abs(j-h) < h,
    lambda: (i//2 | j//2) % 2,
```

Output:

```
     *****
     *****
     *****
     *****
     *****
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********

          
     *    
    ***   
   *****  
  ******* 
 *********
  ******* 
   *****  
    ***   
     *    

  **  **  
  **  **  
**********
**********
  **  **  
  **  **  
**********
**********
  **  **  
  **  **
```

Comment: Aside from lacking any explanation: `eval` is *totally* uncalled for here - please do not help legitimize its overuse to beginner programmers. A pattern could be represented as, for example, a function accepting `i, j, n` parameters, which would also teach something useful about higher-order functions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's so simple I don't think it needs an explanation. I'd find an explanation distracting (I often ignore people's explanations and just read the code, often that's simpler). And I don't see an issue with eval here. I'm not using it on user input, just on my own ints and simple builtins. Originally I used lambdas, but that got annoying not just for the keyword but also because I had to pass `j`. Ugh. Distracted from the actual expressions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ah well, updated, `for` statement not only makes it even simpler but also avoids the need for the parameter...

Comment: I removed my downvote, but please see my answer to get a sense of just how much I think there is to explain here. I already voted to close the question; but I have been trying to figure out a way to write a good canonical for these star-and-space pattern questions generally, so I decided to get in a little practice for the answer portion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well your version is a lot more complicated. So some explanation helps there. Although that *gigantic* amount of talking was so off-putting that I couldn't get myself to even read half of it.

Comment: My version is the `triangle` function plus the last block of code. There is a detailed explanation because I show, step by step, *how* we figure out what goes in the `triangle` function, which also models the original thought process more accurately (figuring out how many spaces and then how many stars to display on each line, rather than figuring out which symbol to display in each individual position as we come to it).

Comment: @Kelly Bundy This is a clever solution (though maybe not at the level of beginning programmers!).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to factor common logic out of your four for loops, and also to use string multiplication to eliminate the inner loops:

```py
patterns = [
    [(1,1),   None],
    [(-1,10), None],
    [(-1,10), (1, 0)],
    [(1,1),   (-1,9)]
]
begun = False
for (sign, plus), leftPat in patterns:
    print('', end = '\n' * begun)
    begun = True
    leftSign, leftPlus = leftPat if leftPat else (0,0)
    for row in range(10):
        print(' ' * (row * leftSign + leftPlus), '*' * (row * sign + plus), sep='')
```

Explanation:

- We populate `patterns` with a list of pairs of tuples (also pairs) that are asterisk params (required) and space params (optional, in other words: can be `None`)
- We iterate over the patterns
- For each pattern, we use default values of (0,0) if the space params (`leftPat`) are `None`
- We then use string multiplication to print the indicated number of spaces followed by the indicated number of asterisks for each row in the pattern
- There is additional logic using `begun` to print blank lines between each pattern

If an extra blank line at the end were acceptable, this could be simplified further to:

```py
for (sign, plus), leftPat in patterns:
    leftSign, leftPlus = leftPat if leftPat else (0,0)
    for row in range(10):
        print(' ' * (row * leftSign + leftPlus), '*' * (row * sign + plus), sep='')
    print()
```